# How to create EditText field without click run intent?

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext

I'm creating a password field. I want to input password and at once star new intent. Her is my code:

```
EditText passwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwd);
passwd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        EditText ryt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPasswd);

        if(ryt.getText().toString().equals("123")) {                    

            Intent intent = new Intent(first.this, second.class);
            startActivity(intent);               
            System.exit(0);

        }
    }
}
```

I wondering how to change onClick method. Maybe some one had similar problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: cant understand whr u problem get ?pls eleboate ur prob

Comment: when I input password (123) I don't want to push anything (any button or firld). After input a password I want automatically run new intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final EditText passwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwd);
```

Witha  final variable you would be able to access it from your inner class.

Answer (score 0):

Erasing `System.exit(0)` might be a good start.